# Find number of days ( comma separated ) between two dates in php

Tags: php, yii2

I have comma separated days(1,3,5,6) and i want to count number of days between two days.

I have done this as below.

```
$days=$model->days; // comma saperated days
$days=explode(',',$days); // converting days into array


$count=0;
$start_date = $model->activity_start_date; // i.e. 2018-03-27
$end_date = date('Y-m-d');


while(strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)){
  if(in_array(date("N",strtotime($start_date)),$days)){ // check for day no
      $count++;
  }
  $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));
}
```

**This code is working fine. But the problem is if difference between two date will be year or more than a year than it loop 365 times or more.**

Is there any way to reduce execution time to count days. Or it is possible to get counts of days using mysql query.

**Real Scenario** :  I have one event which have start date and it occurs multiple in week(i.e. Monday and Wednesday ) and i want to find how many times event occur from start date to now. If start date is 2018-04-9 and today is 2018-05-9 than count will be 9

Comment: you can use mysql function datediff() to get nuber of days between to dates. plz try it. may be it will used for you.                              select datediff('2018-05-08', '2018-05-01');

Comment: Add a sample Input and output format to your question

Comment: input will be start date and output will count of no of days

Comment: So you need `echo count(explode(',',$days));`?

Comment: @Andreas i have one event which have start date and it occurs multiple in week and i want to find how many times event occur from start date to now

Comment: Update you question with input and output, how hard can it be? I voted close now.

Comment: updated question

Comment: If you get dates from a database, most SQL servers implemet such a function. DateDiff in SQL server.

Comment: Don't have comma separated values

Comment: I think there is no way to ignore the loop for this logic, so you have to run till the end of the loop, even whatever the length of the it

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi You don't need to loop for this. See my answer

Comment: Great Andreas; I thought to get each difference values between two dates, Only the last value is required means no loops required as you did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires no looping.

I find how many weeks between start and end and multiply full weeks (in your example 16,17,18) with count of days.
Then I find how many days there is in first week (15) that is higher than or equal to daynumber of startday.
Then the opposit for week 19.

```
$days="1,3"; // comma saperated days
$days=explode(',',$days); // converting days into array


$count=0;
$start_date = "2018-04-09";
$end_date = "2018-05-09";

// calculate number of weeks between start and end date
$yearW = floor(((strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date)) / 86400)/7);

if($yearW >0) $count = ($yearW -1)*count($days); //full weeks multiplied with count of event days    

$startday = date("N", strtotime($start_date));
$endday = date("N", strtotime($end_date));

//find numer of event days in first week (less than or equal to $startday)
$count += count(array_filter($days,function ($value) use($startday) {return ($value >= $startday);}));

//find numer of event days in last week (less than $endday)
$count += count(array_filter($days,function ($value) use($endday) {return ($value < $endday);}));


echo $count; // 9
```

https://3v4l.org/9kupt

Added $yearW to hold year weeks

Comment: @rob006 Updated to handle years.

Comment: It still does not work correctly for some years - year does not always have 52 weeks.

Comment: @rob006 Good point. I calculate the days instead and divide by 7.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have a code I have used previously in a project. It is used to find the distance between date from today.

```
public function diffFromToday($date){
        $today = date('jS F, Y');

        $today = str_replace(',','',$today);
        $today=date_create($today);
        $today = date_format($today,"Y-m-j"); 

        $date = str_replace(',','',$date);
        $date=date_create($date);
        $date = date_format($date,"Y-m-j");

        $today=date_create($today);
        $date=date_create($date);

        $diff=date_diff($today,$date);
        $result = $diff->format("%R%a");
        $result = str_replace('+','',$result);
        return $result;

    }
```

You can use this function according to your requirement. Date format used in this function is `'jS F, Y'` DO not be confused and use your own format to convert.

Comment: I dont need date diffrence , i need to count days which are comma saperated

Comment: You should post this code on code review and let people help you with this. It's really terrible code, you will benefit a lot from it.

Comment: Well, It was the function I have used 2 years ago (Just started learning PHP back then). I just don't modify it and answer as it is but thanks the for the suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This code will return you days count between two different days. It is actually integer number `$diff=date_diff($today,$date);
        echo $diff->format("%R%a");` @Yasin Patel

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_date =  date_create('2018-03-27');
$end_date = date_create('2018-04-27');
$t = ceil(abs($endDate- $start_date) / 86400);
echo date_diff($start_date, $end_date)->format('%a');
```

Output with like this

```
396
```

Comment: I dont need date diffrence , i need to count days which are comma saperated

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use the date->diff function to get the values you can directly use like -5 or 5?

```
$diffInDays = (int)$dDiff->format("%r%a");
```

[Here](http://%20php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) is something for format parameter descriptions if it could be helpful to you.

Comment: I dont need date diffrence , i need to count days which are comma saperated

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`tplaner/when`](https://github.com/tplaner/When) library for this:

```
$days = str_replace(
    ['1',  '2',  '3',  '4',  '5',  '6',  '0',  '7'], 
    ['mo', 'tu', 'sa', 'th', 'fr', 'sa', 'su', 'su'],
    '1,3'
);

$when = new When();
$when->rangeLimit = 1000;
$occurrences = $when->startDate(new DateTime('2018-04-9'))
    ->freq('daily')
    ->byday('mo,we')
    ->getOccurrencesBetween(new DateTime('2018-04-9'), new DateTime('2018-05-9'));

echo count($occurrences);
```

Comment: OP does not have 'mo,we' as input.

Comment: @Andreas Converting `1` to `mo` should not be a challenge.